# TypeError: (intermediate value).mandatoryProps is not iterable

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc, transpiler

I'm getting this error after using transpiled javascript from typescript code.
super keyword is not working as it supposed to I'm trying to access a one property of parent class but it throws error saying TypeError: (intermediate value).mandatoryProps is not iterable

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "declaration": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "outDir": "src",
    },
    "include": [
        "lib/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
    ]
}
```

actual typescript file

```
export abstract class VMSchemaRegistryEvent extends VMEvent {
    @Transform(({ value }) =>
        Object.values(SchemaRegistryNotificationSubject).find((code) => code == value)
        || Object.values(SchemaRegistryRequestEventSubject).find((code) => code == value)
        || Object.values(SchemaRegistryErrorEventSubject).find((code) => code == value))
    schemaRegistryEventSubject: SchemaRegistryEventSubject;

    constructor(schemaRegistryEventSubject: SchemaRegistryEventSubject) {
        super(
            new VMEventIdentity(vmEventsSpecBuilder.buildSchemaRegistryEventName(schemaRegistryEventSubject),
                SCHEMA_REGISTRY_NAMESPACE_CONST))
        this.schemaRegistryEventSubject = schemaRegistryEventSubject;
    }

    static fromPlainObject(baseEvent: any): VMSchemaRegistryEvent {
        return vmEventsSpecBuilder.buildSchemaRegistryConcreteEventFromBaseEvent(baseEvent)
    }

    @Expose()
    get toPlainObject(): StringIndexedObject {
        let objectToReturn: StringIndexedObject = { ...super.toPlainObject }
        objectToReturn[VMEventPropertyKeys.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_EVENT_SUBJECT_KEY] = this.schemaRegistryEventSubject;
        return objectToReturn;
    }

    mandatoryProps: VMEventPropertyKeys[] = [...super.mandatoryProps, VMEventPropertyKeys.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_EVENT_SUBJECT_KEY]
}
```

```
export class VMEvent implements Publishable, Buildable {
    @Type(() => ObjectId)
    @Transform(({ value }) => resolveTimeBasedId(value))
    _id?: ObjectId;

    @Type(() => VMEventIdentity)
    eventIdentity: VMEventIdentity;

    constructor(eventIdentity: object | VMEventIdentity, _id?: string | ObjectId | ObjectIdLike) {
        this._id = resolveOrGenerateTimeBasedId(_id);
        if (vmEventsSpecResolver.isVMEventIdentity(eventIdentity)) {
            this.eventIdentity = eventIdentity;
        } else {
            this.eventIdentity = VMEventIdentity.fromPlainObject(eventIdentity);
        }
    }

    static fromPlainObject(eventPlain: object): VMEvent {
        return plainToClass(VMEvent, eventPlain);
    }

    @Expose()
    get toPlainObject(): StringIndexedObject {
        let objectToReturn: StringIndexedObject = {};
        objectToReturn[VMEventPropertyKeys.EVENT_IDENTITY_KEY] = this.eventIdentity.toPlainObject
        objectToReturn[VMEventPropertyKeys.OBJECT_ID_KEY] = this._id
        return objectToReturn;
    }


    mandatoryProps: VMEventPropertyKeys[] = [VMEventPropertyKeys.EVENT_IDENTITY_KEY]
}
```

transpiled Javascript

```
class VMSchemaRegistryEvent extends vmBaseEvent_1.VMEvent {
    constructor(schemaRegistryEventSubject) {
        super(new vmBaseEvent_1.VMEventIdentity(vmEventsSpecBuilder_1.vmEventsSpecBuilder.buildSchemaRegistryEventName(schemaRegistryEventSubject), vmEventCommonTypes_1.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_NAMESPACE_CONST));
        this.mandatoryProps = [...super.mandatoryProps, vmEventPropertyKeys_1.VMEventPropertyKeys.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_EVENT_SUBJECT_KEY];
        this.schemaRegistryEventSubject = schemaRegistryEventSubject;
    }
    static fromPlainObject(baseEvent) {
        return vmEventsSpecBuilder_1.vmEventsSpecBuilder.buildSchemaRegistryConcreteEventFromBaseEvent(baseEvent);
    }
    get toPlainObject() {
        let objectToReturn = { ...super.toPlainObject };
        objectToReturn[vmEventPropertyKeys_1.VMEventPropertyKeys.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_EVENT_SUBJECT_KEY] = this.schemaRegistryEventSubject;
        return objectToReturn;
    }
}
```

```
class VMEvent {
    constructor(eventIdentity, _id) {
        this.mandatoryProps = [vmEventPropertyKeys_1.VMEventPropertyKeys.EVENT_IDENTITY_KEY];
        this._id = utils_1.resolveOrGenerateTimeBasedId(_id);
        if (vmEventsSpecResolver_1.vmEventsSpecResolver.isVMEventIdentity(eventIdentity)) {
            this.eventIdentity = eventIdentity;
        }
        else {
            this.eventIdentity = VMEventIdentity.fromPlainObject(eventIdentity);
        }
    }
    static fromPlainObject(eventPlain) {
        return class_transformer_1.plainToClass(VMEvent, eventPlain);
    }
    get toPlainObject() {
        let objectToReturn = {};
        objectToReturn[vmEventPropertyKeys_1.VMEventPropertyKeys.EVENT_IDENTITY_KEY] = this.eventIdentity.toPlainObject;
        objectToReturn[vmEventPropertyKeys_1.VMEventPropertyKeys.OBJECT_ID_KEY] = this._id;
        return objectToReturn;
    }
}
```